# Apply styles for sticky nav when main nav goes out of view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve made my navigation for mobile sticky with this code:

```
<div class="stickyTest" id="stickyTest2">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="homeicon"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>" class=""></a></li>
    <?php echo $_menu ?>

  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
      new MobileNavigation();

      var searchToggle = $('mobile-search-toggle'),
          searchForm = $('search_mini_form');
      if (searchToggle && searchForm) {
        searchToggle.observe('click', function() {
          searchForm.toggleClassName('shown');
        });
      }
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxsearchsubmit(form){
      var search = encodeURIComponent(form.w.value);
      document.activeElement.blur();
      window.location="http://www.test.co.uk/search/go?w="+search; 
      return false;
    }
  </script>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.stickyTest {
  background: #362011;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
}
#stickyTest2 {margin-top:40px;}
```

Now my problem is that I only need the `position:fixed` of the `.stickyTest` class and the `margin-top:40px` of the `#stickyTest2` id to be applied for when the user scrolls down and the top navigation goes out of view. So two questions:

1. How do I apply those specific styles on scroll?
2. Is there a way to detect when the top navigation goes out of view? I know I could do something that the sticky nav styles are applied when the user scrolls beyond 200px for example but with different screen sizes etc. I’d like to know if there is a more flexible method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I apply those specific styles on scroll?

**If** **you can use jQuery library**, you can detect the scroll event with this code :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Then you can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to play with class.

> Is there a way to detect when the top navigation goes out of view?

You can get the height of the navigation bar with this piece of code, with jQuery again and do a test in your `scroll()` function with the `scrollTop()` method, like this for instead :

```
var stickyHeight = $('.stickyTest').height(); 
$(window).scroll(function(){
  // if your top navbar is out of view
  if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeight){
    $('.stickyTest').addClass('fixed');
  }else{
    $('.stickyTest').removeClass('fixed');
  } 
});
```

[See a live example](https://jsfiddle.net/s4Ljnto8/3/)

**Source :**

`scroll()` : https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

`addClass()` : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

`removeClass()` : https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

`scrollTop()` : https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/